# How to give the same height to side by side minipages?

Tags: minipage, minted

I tried putting two `minted` environments next to each other. I decided to use `minipage` for that purpose. Each of the `minted` environments has a grey background. Unfortunately, the two code snippets do not have the same height, so there is a visible step between the two boxes.

[image]

**How can I force both minipages to have the same height?**

```
\documentclass[twoside=true, %  doppelseitiger Druck
    DIV=15,% DIV Faktor für Satzspiegelberechnung, sie Doku zu KOMA Script
    BCOR=15mm, % Bindekorrektur
    chapterprefix=false,
    headinclude=true,
    footinclude=false,
    pagesize,%         write pagesize to DVI or PDF
    fontsize=11pt,%             use this font size
    paper=a4,%          use ISO A4
    bibliography=totoc,%         write bibliography-chapter to table of contents
    index=totoc,%         write index-chapter to table of contents
    cleardoublepage=plain,% \cleardoublepage generates pages with pagestyle empty
     headings=big,%       A4/B5
    listof=flat,%        improved list of tables
    numbers=noenddot
  ]{scrbook}

\usepackage{xcolor}         % z.B. für schattierte Boxen
\usepackage[facing=yes]{floatrow}       % mehrere Gleitobjekte nebeneinander/caption neben Bild/Tabelle

\usepackage[chapter,newfloat]{minted}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\setminted{breaklines=true,
           bgcolor=bg,
           curlyquotes=false}

\usemintedstyle{vs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{listing}[tb]
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{minted}{yaml}
                Test
                New Line
            \end{minted}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{minted}{yaml}
                Test
            \end{minted}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
            \caption{\texttt{DeploymentConfig} des Spark-Master}
            \label{lst:deploymentconfigsparkmaster}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
            \caption{\texttt{DeploymentConfig} der Spark-Worker}
            \label{lst:deploymentconfigsparkworker}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{listing}
\end{document}
```

Comment: minipage has another optional argument to specify the height, but note you have two minipage of `0.5\textwidth` but with a word-space between them, so your lines are over full, either use `...\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}....` with no space, or make the pages less than half of text width.

Comment: I'd like to have this specified rather dynamic, according to arbitrary content in the boxes.

Comment: Also, setting the height of the `minipage`s does not set the height of the `minted` boxes.

Comment: It would help if your MWE were executable.  Besides the missing \documentclass, \begin{document} and \end{document}, I get an error for \@chapterlistsgap@on undefined.

Comment: The MWE now compiles.