# vfill in side by side minipages

Tags: pdftex, minipage

Given two texts of different and unknown lengths, I would like to place them side to side (e.g. using two minipages), and placing at the bottom of the minipages **at the same height** a closing text.

As an example, something like this:

```
┌────────────────┬────────────────┐
│ This is a text │ This text is   │
│ of unknown     │ shorter.       │
│ length but it  │                │
│ is pretty      │                │
│ awesome.       │                │
│ (\vskip)       │                │
│ Closing text 1 │ Closing text 2 │
└────────────────┴────────────────┘
```

The longest of the two texts (here on the left) will have a fixed vskip below it and then there will be a closing text. On the other column, where text will be shorter or of the same length, the closing text should be placed at the bottom, at the same height of the other.

I used two minipages with width `0.5\textwidth` and with a `\vfill` before the closing text: they are side by side, but their height differs and `\vfill` does not work (similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/412704/9358)).

How can this be done?

Comment: I **just** realized that a tabular could be used instead of minipages! I'll leave the question open for possible contributions.

Comment: Are 'Closing text 1` and `Closing text 2` each guaranteed to fit in the width of  a `minipage`

Comment: No, they might break on multiple lines.

Comment: And what should be done if the 'closing text' parts occupy differing numbers of columns: should be be aligned top, middle, or bottom?

Comment: Closing text should break as if it was the text above and be aligned on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `tabularx`-based solution.

[image]

If you don't want vertical divider lines, just change `{|L|L|}` to `{@{}LL@{}}`. If you don't want horizontal lines at the top and bottom, just omit the two `\hline` instructions. Change the value of the length parameter `\tabcolsep` (default value: 6pt) to decrease or increase the gap between the columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|L|L|}
\hline
This is a text of unknown length but it is pretty awesome.
\par\vskip2cm % some \vskip instruction
&
This text is shorter. \\
Closing text 1 Closing text 1 Closing text 1 
&
Closing text 2 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using tabularx as well :)