# How to align text with graphics using tabularx?

Tags: graphics, tabularx, alignment, karnaugh

I am trying to align two blocks of text and figures side-by-side using `tabularx`. The document code is based off the [solution given in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/538349/239359). The solution works for text but doesn't seem to work for graphics like Karnaugh maps. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{karnaugh-map}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|L|L|}
\hline
Other text
&
Karnaugh Map \\
Here is a Karnaugh map 
&
\begin{karnaugh-map}(label=corner)[4][4][1][$A$][$B$][$C$][$D$]
    \autoterms[0]
\end{karnaugh-map} \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

This does not produce the output I require. In the picture below, the `Here is a Karnaugh map` should be aligned with the top of the Karnaugh map.

[image]

Would someone be able to help me fix this?

**Edit:** Here is  how I want it to be displayed: [image]

Comment: Please see the last update. (0ption 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}

\usepackage{karnaugh-map}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|L|L|}\hline
        Other text        &   Karnaugh Map  \\
        some more other Text that can be very long  & \\
        Here is a Karnaugh map
        &
        \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\normalbaselineskip}{%
        \begin{karnaugh-map}(label=corner)[4][4][1][$A$][$B$][$C$][$D$]
            \autoterms[0]
        \end{karnaugh-map}} \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I should have made the question clearer. This solution works but it defeats the purpose of using `tabularx` in the first place. The `Other text` portion could be longer than the `Karnaugh map` section, so I want there to be separate alignment points.

Comment: see edited answer

Comment: The `Karnaugh Map` portion should be aligned with the top of the `Other text` section. I have edited my answer to show the desired layout.

Comment: again edited ...

Comment: Ah, I see. Hopefully got it now. See edit